# Google chrome versions do not match

Tags: google-chrome

I updated Google Chrome and verified the version in the terminal with `google-chrome --version` which gave 56.0.2924.87. However, when I launch with `google-chrome`, in the about section the version is still 53.0.2785.116. Why?

Comment: Reboot or kill all chrome processes.

Comment: @Pilot6 Rebooting solved the problem.